# When to use $ Mongo in Meteor calls?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I find this a bit confusing. In one case, you have:

```
return MyData.find({}, {sort: {size: 1}});
```

But then in another case:

```
MyData.update(objId, {$inc: {size: 5}});
```

Why isn't `$sort` used above? How do I know when to use `$` or not?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is a whole section in the documentation that [tells you which which "operators" can be used](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/) with each separate type of operation.

The basic case is that the `$` prefixed items are "operators", or otherwise possibly "variables" within the context of aggregation pipeline stages.

The second document syntax of "sort" is actually specific to ["minimongo"](https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases) in it's choice of how to issue a "sort" modifier to a query. In all other cases the referenced document will apply as to whether this is used with `.find()` or `.update()` or `.aggregate()` in the respective operations.